# Variables can not be used inside bindings

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

I have a validation function that return which part is failing. For example -

```
public class DateValidator{
    public String validateDate(startDate, endDate){
        try{
            LocalDate.parse(startDate, formatter);
            LocalDate.parse(endDate, formatter);
        } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
            return "INVALID_DATE_FORMAT";
        }
        if (startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
            return "INVALID_START_AND_END_DATES";
        }
    ..... so on
    }
}
```

I want to use the this in Drools for Validation as

```
rule
    "ValidateDate"
when
    $error: Error();
    $request: Request();
    DateValidator( $dateValidation: validateDate($request.getStartDate(), $request.getEndDate()) != null);
then
    $error.getBadRequest($dateValidation);
end;
```

I want to use the return type of the variable as not null means the validation did not passed. But I am getting below exception for the DRL file -

```
text=Variables can not be used inside bindings.
Variable [$request] is being used in binding 
'validateDate($request.getStartDate(), $request.getEndDate())']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to execute the function call as part of a `from` Conditional Element:

```
rule
    "ValidateDate"
when
    $error: Error();
    $request: Request(
      $startDate: startDate,
      $endDate: endDate
    );
    $dv: DateValidator()
    $msg: String() from $dv.validateDate($startDate, $endDate)
then
    $error.getBadRequest($msg);
end
```

Hope it helps,